# Is there any way to list connected USB printers in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, printing, uwp

I am developing a POS application in UWP where I have to send print command to connected USB printer. I am unable to detect connected USB printer in windows device in UWP.

Comment: Did you see the [POS Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PosPrinter) from Microsoft?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
var devicePicker = new DevicePicker();
//filter, so you get printer only:
devicePicker.Filter.SupportedDeviceSelectors.Add("System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:=\"{0ecef634-6ef0-472a-8085-5ad023ecbccd}\"");
devicePicker.Show(new Rect());
```

and then

```
devicePicker.Hide();
```

to close the List.

Or you can use something like this to select a device:

```
var devicePicker = new DevicePicker();  
//filter, so you get printer only:
devicePicker.Filter.SupportedDeviceSelectors.Add("System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:=\"{0ecef634-6ef0-472a-8085-5ad023ecbccd}\"");  
DeviceInformation info = await devicePicker.PickSingleDeviceAsync(new Rect());
```

Comment: I tried above logic without adding Filter but "DeviceInformation info" giving null. I may connect any any USB printer, so cannot filter by its GUID.

Comment: Try to use the filter, on my System it worked and listed (multiple) printers. when I do not use the filter i get a lot more devices listed. Maybe you want to take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/enumerate-devices)